# How can I move VBA-JSON output to specific cells in worksheet?

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping

Very new to VBA. Trying to learn as much as I can. I can get the output that I want in the immediate window, but how can I move all of that to my worksheet?

I'm honestly not sure what to try or where to try it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub JsonMain()
    Dim dict
    Dim subDict
    Dim strLine As String

    ' Read from file
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\" + "Main.json"

    Dim nFile As Integer
    Dim strJson As String
    nFile = FreeFile
    Open FilePath For Input As #nFile
    strJson = Input(LOF(nFile), nFile)
    Close #nFile

    Dim jp As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set jp = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strJson)

    Dim gameData As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set gameData = jp("data")

    Dim theseMonsters As Object
    Set theseMonsters = gameData("monsters")

    Debug.Print "there are " & theseMonsters.Count & " monsters in the profile"

    Dim i As Long
    Dim monster As Dictionary
    Dim monsterName As Variant
    Dim monsterDetails As Variant
    For Each monsterName In theseMonsters.Keys
        Debug.Print "Monster #" & monsterName
        Set monsterDetails = theseMonsters(monsterName)
        Debug.Print " --               name: " & monsterDetails("class_name")
        Debug.Print " --        total level: " & monsterDetails("total_level")
        Debug.Print " --         perfection: " & monsterDetails("perfect_rate")
        Debug.Print " --       catch number: " & monsterDetails("create_index")
        Dim battleStats As Collection
        Set battleStats = monsterDetails("total_battle_stats")
        Debug.Print " -- battle stats: ";
        For i = 1 To battleStats.Count
            Debug.Print battleStats.Item(i) & " ";
        Next i
        Debug.Print ""
        ' ...
    Next monsterName
End Sub
```

Edit 1:

Expected results would be bold titles for each category that are printed in row A, with data going down in columns under those titles.

Here is an example output that I get in the immediate window:

Monster #47103
 --               name: Monstratos
 --        total level: 20
 --         perfection: 53.763
 --       catch number: 39
 -- battle stats: 218 288 221 198 227 201

I would like Row A to contain these bold headers: Monster #, Name, Total Level, Perfection, Catch Number, HP, PA, PD, SA, SD, SPD (Battle Stats is not a header, but the individual battle stats are).

Below that, for this mon as an example, would be: 47103, Monstratos, 20, 53.763, 39, 218, 288, 221, 198, 227, 201.

Comment: Please include the Json string

Comment: @QHarr this is all I have at the moment. I'm referencing this JSON though:
https://www.etheremon.com/api/user/get_my_monster?trainer_address=0x2Fef65e4D69a38bf0dd074079f367CDF176eC0De

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like the following. You incremement the row counter, `r`, each time you hit a new *monster* dictionary. For each item of interest within the *monster* dictionary the column increases by 1.

```
Option Explicit  
Public Sub WriteOutBattleInfo()
    Dim headers(), r As Long, i As Long, json As Object, key As Variant, ws As Worksheet, battleStats As Object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    headers = Array("Monster #", "Name", "Total Level", "Perfection", "Catch Number", "HP", "PA", "PD", "SA", "SD", "SPD")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.etheremon.com/api/user/get_my_monster?trainer_address=0x2Fef65e4D69a38bf0dd074079f367CDF176eC0De", False
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("data")("monsters") 'dictionary of dictionaries
    End With
    r = 2
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
    For Each key In json.keys
        With ws
            .Cells(r, 1) = key
            .Cells(r, 2) = json(key)("class_name")
            .Cells(r, 3) = json(key)("total_level")
            .Cells(r, 4) = json(key)("perfect_rate")
            .Cells(r, 5) = json(key)("create_index")
            Set battleStats = json(key)("total_battle_stats")

            For i = 1 To battleStats.Count
                .Cells(r, i + 5) = battleStats.item(i)
            Next i
        End With
        r = r + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want. It even references the link instead of the json file which is 10x better - more up to date and dont have to download. Thank you so much.